# RGB-Color-Range to HSV-Color-Range

Tags: python, opencv, rgb, mask, hsv

I want to detect some Colormarkers in an Video.
[Example Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nKiL.jpg).
To achieve this i let the user select the color points in the First Frame and get rgb values.

```
# User input for each point
flag, frame = capture.read()
frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
x1, y1, r1, g1, b1 = SupportMainClasses.Pixelcollector(frame).getXY()
x2, y2, r2, g2, b2 = SupportMainClasses.Pixelcollector(frame).getXY()
x3, y3, r3, g3, b3 = SupportMainClasses.Pixelcollector(frame).getXY()
```

Were P1 is the static point of the ring suspension, and P2 & P3 are color markers i want to detect. Afterwards i switch from rgb to grb and apply a range.

```
#define Color Range in GRB
colorRange = 30
picked_p2 = (b2, g2, r2)
upper_p2 = (b2 + colorRange if b2 + colorRange < 255 else 255, g2 + colorRange if g2 + colorRange < 255 else 255, r2 + colorRange if r2 + colorRange < 255 else 255)
lower_p2 = (b2 - colorRange if b2 - colorRange > 0 else 0, g2 - colorRange if g2 - colorRange > 0 else 0, r2 - colorRange if r2 - colorRange > 0 else 0)
picked_p3 = (b3, g3, r3)
upper_p3 = (b3 + colorRange if b3 + colorRange < 255 else 255, g3 + colorRange if g3 + colorRange < 255 else 255, r3 + colorRange if r3 + colorRange < 255 else 255)
lower_p3 = (b3 - colorRange if b3 - colorRange > 0 else 0, g3 - colorRange if g3 - colorRange > 0 else 0, r3 - colorRange if r3 - colorRange > 0 else 0)
```

so far so good, until here it works like intended. [Display of picked color and Range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0YBp.png)

but after i try to convert that grb range to a hsv range and to build a Mask of that specific range

```
#Color Masks
p2Mask = cv.inRange(cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV), cv.cvtColor(np.uint8([[list(lower_p2)]]), cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV), cv.cvtColor(np.uint8([[list(upper_p2)]]), cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV))
p3Mask = cv.inRange(cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV), cv.cvtColor(np.uint8([[list(lower_p3)]]), cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV), cv.cvtColor(np.uint8([[list(upper_p3)]]), cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV))
```

it wont detect my color, and trying to Print the values

```
print(lower_p2)
print(upper_p2)

print(cv.cvtColor(np.uint8([[list(lower_p2)]]), cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV))
print(cv.cvtColor(np.uint8([[list(upper_p2)]]), cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV))
```

returns:

```
lowerP2GRB:         (126, 149, 110)
upperP2GRB:         (186, 209, 170)
lowerP2HSV:         [[[ 72  67 149]]]
upperP2HSV:         [[[ 72  48 209]]]
```

In earlier Version i converted first to hsv and made the range in hsv witch worked fine. The interesting thing here is that the hue is 72 for upper and lower. Which means for me, the rgb volume gets Transformed into a area in hsv.
[Conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnSMr.png)

But i need a Volume in hsv to build the mask (?).
[Conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBjhZ.png)

How do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The whole code:

```
import logging as log
import argparse as arg
import cv2 as cv
import math as math
import os as os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter

import SupportMainFunctions
import SupportMainClasses

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'setup logger'
log.basicConfig(level=log.DEBUG, filename='temp/log.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'setup csv to log detected point data'

try:
    os.remove('temp/pointData.csv')
    csvWriter = open('temp/pointData.csv', 'a', newline='')
except:
    print("Error while deleting file ", 'temp/pointData.csv')

csvWriter = open('temp/pointData.csv', 'a', newline='')


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'setup arguments'
parser = arg.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--inputPath', help="path to input Video" ,default='resources/test_video2.MOV')

args = parser.parse_args()

log.info("Video Path : '{}'" .format(args.inputPath))

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'Video Capture Init'
capture = cv.VideoCapture(args.inputPath)

'Background substraction init'
backSub = cv.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN()

'Get Video Properties'
frame_count = capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
frame_width = capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
frame_height = capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
fps = capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)
video_codec = capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FOURCC)
video_name = args.inputPath.split(".")[0].split("/")[1]

'Log Properties'
log.info("Total Number of Frames : '{}'" .format(frame_count))
log.info("Frame width : '{}'" .format(frame_width))
log.info("Frame height : '{}'" .format(frame_height))
log.info("FPS : '{}'" .format(fps))
log.info("Video Codec : '{}'" .format(SupportMainFunctions.decode_fourcc(video_codec)))
log.info("Video Name : '{}'" .format(video_name))

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'Video Writer Init'
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1')
writer = cv.VideoWriter('temp/output.MOV', fourcc, int(fps), (int(frame_width), int(frame_height)), True)

# User input for each point
flag, frame = capture.read()
frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
x1, y1, r1, g1, b1 = SupportMainClasses.Pixelcollector(frame).getXY()
x2, y2, r2, g2, b2 = SupportMainClasses.Pixelcollector(frame).getXY()
x3, y3, r3, g3, b3 = SupportMainClasses.Pixelcollector(frame).getXY()


#define Color Range in GRB
colorRange = 30
picked_p2 = (b2, g2, r2)
upper_p2 = (b2 + colorRange if b2 + colorRange < 255 else 255, g2 + colorRange if g2 + colorRange < 255 else 255, r2 + colorRange if r2 + colorRange < 255 else 255)
lower_p2 = (b2 - colorRange if b2 - colorRange > 0 else 0, g2 - colorRange if g2 - colorRange > 0 else 0, r2 - colorRange if r2 - colorRange > 0 else 0)
picked_p3 = (b3, g3, r3)
upper_p3 = (b3 + colorRange if b3 + colorRange < 255 else 255, g3 + colorRange if g3 + colorRange < 255 else 255, r3 + colorRange if r3 + colorRange < 255 else 255)
lower_p3 = (b3 - colorRange if b3 - colorRange > 0 else 0, g3 - colorRange if g3 - colorRange > 0 else 0, r3 - colorRange if r3 - colorRange > 0 else 0)

#define window size
cv.namedWindow('video', cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.resizeWindow('video', 960, 540)

'Work'
while capture.isOpened():
    flag, frame = capture.read()
    if flag is True:

        #Foreground Mask
        fgMask = backSub.apply(frame)

        print(lower_p3)
        print(upper_p3)

        print(cv.cvtColor(np.uint8([[list(lower_p3)]]), cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV))
        print(cv.cvtColor(np.uint8([[list(upper_p3)]]), cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV))

        #Color Masks
        p2Mask = cv.inRange(cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV), cv.cvtColor(np.uint8([[list(lower_p2)]]), cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV), cv.cvtColor(np.uint8([[list(upper_p2)]]), cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV))
        p3Mask = cv.inRange(cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV), cv.cvtColor(np.uint8([[list(lower_p3)]]), cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV), cv.cvtColor(np.uint8([[list(upper_p3)]]), cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV))

        #Final Mask
        p2Maske = cv.bitwise_and(p2Mask, fgMask, mask=None)
        p3Maske = cv.bitwise_and(p3Mask, fgMask, mask=None)

        # Apply HoughCircle transform on the blurred image.
        detected_circles_p2 = cv.HoughCircles(cv.blur(p2Maske, (3, 3)), cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=20, param2=10, minRadius=5, maxRadius=20)
        detected_circles_p3 = cv.HoughCircles(cv.blur(p3Maske, (3, 3)), cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=20, param2=10, minRadius=5, maxRadius=30)

        # calculate Point positions
        if detected_circles_p2 is not None and detected_circles_p3 is not None:

            # range between picked points
            lenghtP12 = round(math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1))
            lenghtP23 = round(math.hypot(x3 - x2, y3 - y2))

            # Calculate P2 by range of users inputrange and P1
            calclenghtP12 = []
            for pointP2 in detected_circles_p2[0]:
                calclenghtP12.append(round(math.hypot(pointP2[0] - x1, pointP2[1] - y1)))
            calcP2 = detected_circles_p2[0][SupportMainFunctions.find_nearest(calclenghtP12, lenghtP12)]

            # Calculate P3 by range of users Inputrange and P2
            calclenghtP23 = []
            for pointP3 in detected_circles_p3[0]:
                calclenghtP23.append(round(math.hypot(pointP3[0] - calcP2[0], pointP3[1] - calcP2[1])))
            calcP3 = detected_circles_p3[0][SupportMainFunctions.find_nearest(calclenghtP23, lenghtP23)]

            # Draw P1 by user input
            cv.circle(frame, (x1, y1), 1, (0, 0, 255), 3)

            # Draw the circumference of the circle.
            cv.circle(frame, (calcP2[0], calcP2[1]), calcP2[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv.circle(frame, (calcP3[0], calcP3[1]), calcP3[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)

            # Draw a small circle (of radius 1) to show the center.
            cv.circle(frame, (calcP2[0], calcP2[1]), 1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
            cv.circle(frame, (calcP3[0], calcP3[1]), 1, (0, 0, 255), 3)

            #Write Point Data to csv
            csvWriter.write(str(x1) + ", " + str(x2) + ", " + str(calcP2[0]) + ", " + str(calcP2[1]) + ", " + str(calcP3[0]) + ", " + str(calcP3[1]) + "\n")
        else:
            log.info("Missing Circle in frame Nr : '{}'".format(capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)))

        #show current frame with frame nr
        cv.rectangle(frame, (0, 0), (100, 25), (255, 255, 255), -1)
        cv.putText(frame,"Frame: " + str(capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)), (0, 15), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0))



        #draw rectangle to range identification
        cv.rectangle(frame, (0, 25), (25, 50), (255, 255, 255), -1)
        cv.putText(frame, str("P2"), (0, 40), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0))
        cv.rectangle(frame, (25, 25), (50, 50), lower_p2, -1)
        cv.rectangle(frame, (50, 25), (75, 50), picked_p2, -1)
        cv.rectangle(frame, (75, 25), (100, 50), upper_p2, -1)

        cv.rectangle(frame, (0, 50), (25, 75), (255, 255, 255), -1)
        cv.putText(frame, str("P3"), (0, 70), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0))
        cv.rectangle(frame, (25, 50), (50, 75), lower_p3, -1)
        cv.rectangle(frame, (50, 50), (75, 75), picked_p3, -1)
        cv.rectangle(frame, (75, 50), (100, 75), upper_p3, -1)

        cv.imshow('video', p2Mask)

        #quit hook
        if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

        #write Frame to video
        writer.write(frame)

    else:
        break

'Release everything'
capture.release()
writer.release()
csvWriter.close()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```